# QGIS - Clip: Differences between processing commands and built-in Python console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, clip

Two geometries can be clipped in various ways. I have expected the same result, but I got two different results. The following method I used.

I have selected the clip function and added two layers. The green feature is the correct result. The geometry has been clipped by the blue layer. Then I get the following result:

[image]

All processing commands are available from the QGIS built-in Python console. I used the function 'qgis: clip'.

`processing.runandload('qgis:clip', layer1, layer2, None)`

Then I get the following incorrect result:

[image]

It seems to me as if the blue layer is empty or is ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

The Feature (orange frame, layer1) should be cut at the blue layer (layer2).

[image]

What I do not understand is why the clip function of QGIS works. To find under: Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Clip.

[image]

When I run the following code, I get an incorrect result:

`processing.runandload('qgis:clip', layer1, layer2, None)`

Even if I reverse the two layers, I get the same result:

[image]

Why I do not get the same result? Take the tools not the same clip function?

Comment: Where do `layer1` and `layer2` come from? Is there any output in the message log, processing tab? Or in the processing history?

Comment: Did you try switching `layer1` and `layer2` (e.g. `processing.runandload('qgis:clip', layer2, layer1, None)`?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: To me it simply looks like you switched layer 1 and 2 in the second approach. Would be helpful if you provide images of layer 1 and 2 alone. So it's easier to understand which layers you are using and want to clip.

Comment: Even if I reverse the two layers, I get the same incorrect result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use the function *intersection*. Returns a geometry representing the points shared by this geometry and other. This function gives me the desired result.

See: [QgsGeometry::intersection](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#ab18960bbd09b8d204ca62c24b3603ff7)